# How can I configure Apache Tomcat to output a timezone in the timestamp of the catalina.out file?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to configure Apache Tomcat 9 to output a timezone with the timestamp in the catalina.out file.  Right now, I'm just using the default logging.properties configuration, the pertinent part shown here:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8
```

I tried using the "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter" in place of the "org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter", like so:

```
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.format = "%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$tz %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%n"
```

I can see it's using the SimpleFormatter because the timestamp format does change slightly.  However, it does not change to what I specified in the "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.format" property.

Is there a way to do this without switching to use something like log4j?  What am I missing in my configuration?

Apache Tomcat 9.0.22
OpenJDK 1.8.0_222

Edit:

Here are some examples showing the first line of output of Tomcat on startup.  From the default configuration "logging.properties" file (distributed with the Apache Tomcat tar.gz distribution), I get the following on startup:

```
20-Nov-2019 11:46:45.056 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.22
```

If I modifiy the "conf/logging.properties" file, changing the "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter" property like so:

```
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I now get this:

```
Nov 20, 2019 11:50:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.22
```

As the first event in the file (it's actually 2 lines).  So it actually changed which tells me I'm in the right place.  Now I would like to format the line.

When I set the format property:

```
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%d %5p %tz %c{1}:%L:(%t) - %m%n
```

I get the following on startup:

```
Nov 20, 2019 11:56:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.22
```

which looks essentially identical to the log output where the format property was not set.

Comment: you can use something like this `%d %5p %c{1}:%L:(%t) - %m%n`

Comment: @roottraveller I tried setting the format property as you specified (while using the "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter" for the formatter as shown in my example), and I see no difference in the output of the timestamp in the catalina.out.

Comment: How about an example of how it looks before and after you change it from the default?

Comment: Made some edits to the main description with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the format is not enough. you also need to explicitly tell the logger to use this format:

add this to your logging.properties file:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$tz %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%n"
```

For each logger add this line: (example on the Catalina logger)

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

like this:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8
```

After your logger will use the right formatter you can play with the format to fit your timestamp/timezone needs.

Don't forget to restart the Tomcat.

Let me know if you need anything else.